# Omit unwanted char in each regex result

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like

```
76/,2., 115., 12, 5/e12, .111 107,/1, 108/61a, f457f/3 11/150
```

and I would like to find the following values inside:

```
76/2, 115, 12, 5/12, 111, 107/1, 108/61, 457/3 and 11/150
```

Note, that for `107,/1` I want `107/1`, but for `107, /1` I would want `107` and `1`, same for `76/,2`.
I try with [this regex](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5Cd%7B1%2C5%7D%5B%5E.%2F%5Cs%3B%5D*%2F*%5B%5E%5Cd%5Cs.%2F%3B%5D*%5Cd%7B0%2C5%7D&test_string=76%2F%2C2.%2C%20115.%2C%2012%2C%205%2Fe12%2C%20.111%20107%2C%2F1%2C%20108%2F61a%2C%20f457f%2F3%2011%2F150&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=1), but I don't know how to keep only numeric and (if there is) a slash character inside results.

Is it possible? I can just iterate over results and check if each one contains unwanted chars and remove them, but I hoped to find a regex way to do it.

Comment: You cannot get the result you need with just a single regex matching operation, since the matches you want are not contiguous (there is no `76/2` in the string). You will have to use some post-processing step here.

Comment: is it obligatory to add `and` word between items?

Comment: [`[^\d\s]*(\d+)(?:[^\d\s/]*(/)[^\d\s]*(\d+))?[^\s\d]*` replace with `$1$2$3`](https://regex101.com/r/NAxUuk/1)?

Comment: Try adding captures to your regex. Here is a modified regex that does it: (\d{1,5})[^./\s;]*(/)?[^\d\s./;]*(\d{0,5})

Comment: Why do you want a regex solution if you know you can easily filter the characters while iterating?

Comment: @wwii, if I can use one tool and there is no need to write more code, I would go into that, unless it's very complicated.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your advices, finally I'm able to get desired results using different solutions from both ctwheels and RomanPerekhrest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of inventing tangled regex pattern consider straight-forward `re.sub()` solution:

```
import re

s = '76/,2., 115., 12, 5/e12, .111 107,/1, 108/61a, f457f/3 11/150'
result = re.sub(r'\S+[^,\s](,)?', 
                lambda m: re.sub(r'[^\d/]+', '', m.group()) + (m.group(1) or ''), s)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
76/2, 115, 12, 5/12, 111 107/1, 108/61, 457/3 11/150
```

**----------**

To get just a list of the needed values the above can be shortened to:

```
s = '76/,2., 115., 12, 5/e12, .111 107,/1, 108/61a, f457f/3 11/150'
result = re.sub(r'\S+', lambda m: re.sub(r'[^\d/]+', '', m.group()), s).split()

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['76/2', '115', '12', '5/12', '111', '107/1', '108/61', '457/3', '11/150']
```

Comment: The list is my desired output, thanks a lot. This is a neat solution.